# DAG straight to failed and not retrying

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG that runs every morning, it has a task that checks if the origin table as new rows, if there are no new rows it raises an error:

```
def check_before_absolution(ds, **context):
    pd_data_from_gbq = pandas.read_gbq(query      = query_check_data,
                                       project_id = "XXXXXXX",
                                       dialect    = "standard")

    data_count = pd_data_from_gbq["count_row"].iloc[0]
    print("Quantity of new rows " + str(data_count) )
    if str(data_count) == "0":
        raise ValueError("There were no origin rows")
```

The DAG is configured to retry 5 times with 60 minutes between retry:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'XXXXXX',
    'email': [
            "XXXXX@XXXXX.com",
            "XXXXX@XXXXX.com",
            "XXXXX@XXXXX.com", 
            "XXXXX@XXXXX.com"
    ],
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
}
with DAG( dag_id="DAG_1",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval= "0 12 * * *",
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60), 
    start_date= datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 7),
    catchup = False) as dag:
```

Is there a reason why a DAG could skip the up-to-retry even if it was marked as UP-FOR-RETRY in the log?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW0WP.png)

I checked the log and it says that was correctly marked for retry, but it failed and there is no log for the other retries that it should've done.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Airflow are you running?

Comment: Version : 1.10.3-composer on GCP

Comment: Did it ever successfully re-tried the task before?

Comment: Nope, today it worked, it appears that the dagrun_timeout was failing the DAG before it could retry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be that your dagrun_timeout is also set to be 60 minutes. So your dag times out before it had the chance to re-try the task.

Comment: Yeah!! That was it!! Thanks! :D